# How can update multiple documents using multiple targets

Tags: mongodb, go, mongo-go

#### example documents

```
{"id": 1, "alive":true},
{"id": 2, "alive":true},
{"id": 3, "alive":true},
{"id": 4, "alive":true}
```

#### problem

if got targets like `var targetIds []int{1, 3, 4}`. Want to update multiple documents's alive value to false. Currently using this way.

```
var targetIds []int{1, 3, 4}
collection := MongoClient.Database("my_database").Collection("my_collection")
updateDoc := bson.M {
    "$set": bson.M {
        "alive": false,
    }
}
for _, targetId := range targetIds{
    filter := bson.M{
        "id": targetId,
    }
    _, err := collection.UpdateOne(context.Background(), filter, updateDoc)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}
```

for example in postgresql can use this way

```
UPDATE [my_table] SET alive = false WHERE id IN [targetIds];
```

not using for loop. one query like the way in example postgresql query

is there similar way in Go mongodb driver?

Comment: Try google before posting a question. [$in](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Collection.UpdateMany()`](https://pkg.go.dev/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo#Collection.UpdateMany) instead of [`Collection.UpdateOne()`](https://pkg.go.dev/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo#Collection.UpdateOne), and construct a filter that matches the slice of IDs:

```
filter := bson.M{
    "id": bson.M{"$in": targetIds},
}
_, err := collection.UpdateMany(context.Background(), filter, updateDoc)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
```